# JSON Property of non-object & Invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I have a wordpress function that calls an API via Zebra_cURL and then uses `json_decode` to render the data appropriately. Yet there is erratic behavior and the following two errors are occurring: `Trying to get property of non-object in [template file] on line 42` and through lines 50.

The lines in question are below:

```
//Course display callback function
 function display_courses($result) {
        $result->body = json_decode(html_entity_decode($result->body));
        $title = $result->body[0]->{'Title'};
        $term = $result->body[0]->{'Term'};
        $meetings = $result->body[0]->{'Meetings'};
        $status = $result->body[0]->{'Status'};
        $course_number = $result->body[0]->{'OfferingName'};
        $clean_course_number = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $course_number);
        $credits = $result->body[0]->{'Credits'};
        $instructor = $result->body[0]->{'InstructorsFullName'};
        $description = $result->body[0]->{'SectionDetails'}[0]->{'Description'};
    }
```

And then later I get an error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [template file] on line 64` which is:

```
    //Call callback function    
            function parse_courses($result) {
                $result->body = json_decode(html_entity_decode($result->body));
                $course_data = array();
                    foreach($result->body as $course) {
                    [code]
            }
                   [more code]
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here to cause these errors?

Here's a link to [the full template file](https://github.com/ksascomm/ksas_flagship_academic_f5/blob/scss/template-courses-undergrad.php). Apologies for the vast code dump but I'm a bit in over my head with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must always verify the output of **functions/methods** if the result if "**as expected**"
In your case, you did not check what `json_decode()` has returned

```
function parse_courses($result) {
    $result = json_decode(html_entity_decode($result->body));
    if ((!is_array ($result) && !is_object($result)) || 
        (is_array($result) || count($result) == 0) ||
        (json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE)) { // only for PHP >= 5.3.0

        // log the error or warning here ...
        // $input  = $result;
        // $output = print_r ($result, TRUE);

        // Only for PHP >= 5.3.0
        // json_last_error();
        // json_last_error_msg();
        return -1;
    }
    $result->body = $result;
    $course_data = array();
    foreach($result->body as $course) {
        [code]
    }
    [more code]
}
```